I don't understand the notation in Mechanical engineering. Could you help me to understand it better?
Consider a particle $M$ occupying the position $\vec{a}$ at time $t = 0$ and the position $\vec{x}$ at time $t$. A function $f = f(M, t)$ associated with a particle $M$ (e.g., its velocity, acceleration, or other physical quantities to be defined subsequently) can be represented in two different ways during the motion:
$$
f(M, t) = g(\vec{a}, t) \quad \text{or} \quad f(M, t) = h(\vec{x}, t),
$$
where $\vec{x} = \Phi(\vec{a}, t)$; that is to say
$$
h(\Phi(\vec{a}, t), t) = g(\vec{a}, t).
$$
$\textbf{Definition 1.5.}$
1.$ \textit{The Eulerian derivatives of $f$ are the quantities}$
$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i}(\vec{x}, t), \quad \frac{\partial h}{\partial t}(\vec{x}, t).
$$
2. $\textit{The Lagrangian derivatives of $f$ are the quantities}$
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial a_i}(\vec{a}, t), \quad \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(\vec{a}, t).
$$
In mechanical engineering the derivative $\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\right)(\vec{a}, t)$ is denoted $ \frac{dh}{dt}$ or $ \frac{Dh}{Dt}$ (or $ \frac{df}{dt}$ or $ \frac{Df}{Dt}$) and is sometimes called the total derivative of $f$.
I don't understand the notation in Mechanical engineering.

In mechanical engineering the derivative $\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\right)(\vec{a}, t)$ is denoted $ \frac{dh}{dt}$ or $ \frac{Dh}{Dt}$ (or $ \frac{df}{dt}$ or $ \frac{Df}{Dt}$) and is sometimes called the total derivative of $f$.

Is this derivative is known as material derivative?
What does that mean?
$\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\right)(\vec{a}, t)=\frac{dh}{dt}(\vec{x}, t).$ How does these quantities same? I am confused with these notations. could you help me to understand this concept better?

Please delete your prior duplicate questions; In the future, please don't duplicate your questions.

it is not duplicate. both are different questions. if I ask the two questions in same. i will get reported. that is why asked seperately.

Maybe, but It seems that 90% is the same; perhaps that is the context. But Is it not possible to ask your doubts in one question?
